# When will you be demoted?

Tags: clash-royale

It appears that you'll be demoted to a lower arena if you perform badly. However, I wasn't demoted immediately from arena 3 when I reached lower then 800 trophies, while 800 is the limit to be promoted into arena 3.

What is the limit for each arena to be demoted?

Comment: The information when you are promoted (e.g. 800 trophies for arena 3) is given in-game.

Comment: My guess and own feel from the couple of time this has happened to me is that there's about 100 throphies of leeway before you actually get demoted. However, this hasn't happened to me enough for me to confidently put this as an answer.

Comment: @DJPirtu I think the number is slightly lower. I was demoted to arena 2, but I think I haven't lost *that* much trophies.

Comment: I can see how this could vary by arena. My experiences come from slightly higher arenas (4-6). And, as said, it has only happened a couple of times, so this was only my fuzzy recollection of those times. Also, 100 thropies is only worth 3 losses (34 trophies each, so to a slightly lower level opponents).

Comment: I usually get demoted after losing the game after I go under the threshold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get officially ***demoted*** when you reach **50 trophies below the threshold** for a given Arena.  You will receive an in-game notification when this occurs.  Similarly, you get ***promoted*** when you reach you **cross the threshold** listed for a given Arena.  You can view the thresholds for all Arenas at any time by tapping the picture of the Arena you are currently in above the "Battle" button on the Battle tab.

[image: Arena Threshold]

As others have noticed, [you can visit](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258528/what-is-the-differences-between-being-home-and-away) the Arena above or below your Arena, if you are close to the threshold and get matched with someone who has qualified for that Arena.  Chests you are awarded for victory will be locked to the Arena where the match took place.

Note however, that the ***Free Chest, Crown Chest, and Shop*** will all reflect Cards and Gold according to the Arena **you are actually qualified for.**  This is the main difference of being on one side or the other of the threshold.

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you are demoted as soon as you reach the threshold. Similarly, you SHOULD be promoted as soon as you reach the threshold (eh 1100) but sometimes it happens earlier. You might get to play on arena 4 with 1050 trophies simply because there is no one currently looking for a fight from arena 3 that has as much trophies as you, and would be a suitable match, and yet, there is someone from arena 4 (say 1101 trophies) looking for a fight, that the system says is the best match for you. That's why when you start the game you see "Visitor You" sometimes.

TLDR: If the system finds you a player to fight, that has few trophies more, and is one arena above, you'll fight each other instead of waiting 20s or 20m for player your arena and your trophies to come.

Source: Personal experience.

Comment: This seems to be more about the arena _during the match_ instead of the ranking arena. Also, I'm not sure what you're refeing to with "Visitor You".

Comment: When a match starts, one of the players is "Home" and the other is "Visitor". He meant that you might sometimes be a Visitor. @DJPirtu