# What is the differences between being home and away?

Tags: clash-royale

Theres always a Home and an Away player on matches.

What does being the Home or Away player change?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Home player determines the Arena where the battle is fought.  The Arena, affects the [**quality of the loot**](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Chests) which is dropped.  Either opponent who wins will get a Chest from the Home player's Arena.

Answer (score 1):

The battle always takes place in Home player's arena. There is no other difference between the two.

Comment: Not always. I have been a visitor to a player with less trophies than me

Comment: Strange, I was sure that was the case at a point. Well, one exception removes the rule, I edit my answer.