# Once demoted to a lower arena, can you still get the higher arena cards?

Tags: clash-royale

If I was in arena 4 but got demoted back to arena 3, will I still get the arena 4 cards?

Answer (score 5):

Nope, your chests are tied to your current - not highest - arena level.  If you make it to the top and then fall back to arena 1, you'll get arena 1 chests with arena 1 cards.

Answer (score 3):

While what [agent86](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/13845/agent86) said is true, if you have any chests over from the higher arena, they will still contain those arena's cards. So yes, you will still get arena 4 *cards* but you will not get arena 4 *chests*. Therefore, the only way to get the arena 4 cards would be if there were arena 4 cards in the shop before you were demoted, or if you had any arena 4 chests.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the answer is **yes** (to your title, at least), but only in a very specific circumstance.  As I mentioned [**here**](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/258528/what-is-the-differences-between-being-home-and-away) - the Arena you play in determines what the awards will be for either player if they are the victor.  You can therefore get a Chest from a higher Arena if you are high enough and get lucky (both by getting matched to a higher Arena, and winning that match).

Answer (score 0):

No. But I have discovered that if you unlock a card from a arena, and then fall back down, you can still get more of that card.

Answer (score -1):

No. what ever arena you are in, is what arena cards your gonna get... If your in arena 4 and drop down to 3, you'll still get your chests from 4; and then once your out... Your gonna get lvl 3 arena cards only;)

Answer (score -1):

What everyone answered is true. However, you can also still request the higher-arena cards if you have already recieved them.